# Excluding attribute from the dotCover console

Tags: dotcover

I'm trying to use the AttributeFilter option from the command-line to remove classes with the [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] attribute.

So far I've tried:

```
/AttributeFilters=-:ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute
/AttributeFilters=-:System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute
/AttributeFilters=-:^System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$
```

None of these work.

Comment: What language are you using? What is the dotCover console?

Comment: I'm using dotCover in Windows. By console I mean running dotCover from the command-line. I talked to their tech support and it turns out you don't use the "-:" or "+:" syntax. So, /AttributeFilters=System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage" will work.

Answer (score 1):

/AttributeFilters=System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage

You don't use the -: or +: syntax in the /AttributeFilters option only the /Filters option.